# TypeScript + jQuery + JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, web, typescript2.0

Excuse me for this question....
But, Is it possible to use TypeScript in conjunction with jQuery in Java web app development (JSPs)?
I tried. but no luck.
If not possible, then what is the way through which I can make the JavaScript/jQuery code written in JSPs type safe and use new ES6 features without worry?

Pls help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using JSP has nothing to do with your choice of javascript technologies, so as far as that part of your question goes, yes, it is possible to use JSP and javascript together.

Comment: My concern is about TypeScript or its alternative in JSPs

Comment: JSP is just a special servlet that generate HTML. Any frontend technology (TypeScript,Coffeescript, etc) that work on your browser should work in JSP.

Comment: @ST.Kee you mean that I would be able to write raw TypeScript in JSP?

Comment: I believe if you are using typescript you are going to transpile it into javascript anyway. Hence, yes, typescript is usable.